# Not able to add favicon in gatsby config file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, gatsby, favicon

Even after adding favicon to gatsby hello world starter project in gatsby config file, its not working.
I tried googling and searched in stackoverflow for similar question, [How do i add favicon gatsby-config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458658/how-do-i-add-favicon-gatsby-config-js). But that doesn't help or i maybe wrong somewhere.

Please correct me!!

GATSBY CONFIG.JS

```
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/
 */

module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "xxxxxxx",
    author: "Subin",
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-contentful",
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-sass",
    // this plugin will pull all the files in our project system
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "src",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
        icon: `../src/images/favicon-32x32.png`,
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    // REMARK plugin needed to extract the markdown files and parses
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
      options: {
        plugins: [
          "gatsby-remark-relative-images",
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 750,
              linkImagesOriginal: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

PROJECT DIRECTORY IMAGE

[Image : Tree hierarchy of my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qtlh.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display your favicon, you need to have the gatsby-plugin-manifest installed, it doesn't come with the hello world starter.

```sh
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-manifest
```

And here is your `gatsby-config.js` with some default settings to this plugin:

```js
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/
 */

module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "xxxxxxx",
    author: "Subin"
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-contentful",
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-sass",
    // this plugin will pull all the files in our project system
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "src",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
        icon: `../src/images/favicon-32x32.png`
      }
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    // REMARK plugin needed to extract the markdown files and parses
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
      options: {
        plugins: [
          "gatsby-remark-relative-images",
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 750,
              linkImagesOriginal: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: "xxx",
        short_name: "xxxx",
        start_url: "/",
        background_color: "#6b37bf",
        theme_color: "#6b37bf",
        // Enables "Add to Homescreen" prompt and disables browser UI (including back button)
        // see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#display
        display: "standalone",
        icon: "src/images/favicon-32x32.png" // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Remember **to stop your development server and start a brand new one when modifying `gatsby-config.js` in order to see your changes**.

Can you try this and let me know if it works as intended?